# JSON loads from Local Server, but it doesnt from Remote Server

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I am new to coding and i just finished testing my codes from Local server and moving them up to the remote server. Everything works ok when it is on local server, but when i uploaded them onto the remote server,(everything works fine, except 1 class file). 
For this 1 specific class file that is having problem, when it was on local server, the loading speed was already slow, i am wondering if it is because i am passing 3 URLREQUEST Thru it. But it doesn't load at all when it is on Remote server.

I am wondering if i split them up and using addChild into other class files if that would help. Thanks for your time!

```
            Mend = new URLRequest("http://rentaid.info/myaccount_1.php");
            Mend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            variablesss = new URLVariables();
            variablesss.username = s7.statusname.text;
            Mend.data = variablesss;


            nLoader = new URLLoader();
            nLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            nLoader.load(Mend);


            Send = new URLRequest("http://rentaid.info/Autojson.php");
            Send.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            ALoader = new URLLoader();
            ALoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            ALoader.load(Send);


            Send1 = new URLRequest("http://rentaid.info/Accountinfo.php");
            Send1.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            ALoader1 = new URLLoader();
            ALoader1.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            ALoader1.load(Send1);
                ALoader1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,Sandler1);
```

Comment: Please format (indent) correctly your code, and reduce it to the smallest possible code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I am not sure if i need the parser part included, but i removed that for now, to keep it cleaner. Not sure if the code doesn't load on remote server because i have too many URLREQUEST.

Comment: Judging by your code example, you have hardcoded the URLs pointing to `localhost`. This won't work while on the remote server. If this was an error when copying/pasting the code to here, please provide info on which loader that's failing and what error you are given. Add the event listeners for the `SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR` and `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` to the `URLLoader`s and trace out the error. It will help in weeding out the problem.

Comment: Hi, i just changed the URL to the remote server address, every other loader works ok, except this class. It doesn't echo any error, it just simply doesnt load, but when i replace the URL to localhost, then everything works fine(except its a little slow). I am wondering if the loading time is a problem, and if i split each Load into their own class file, if that would help at all.

Comment: Is your live swf running on the same domain as the live php code?

Comment: By the way, http://rentaid.info/Autojson.php isn't found. It gives a 404. Make sure you have uploaded all server-side code to your remote server and try again.

Comment: Hey sorry when i was cleaning up the code above, i deleted a few letters by mistake, but the URL is correct in my class file, and i am just testing the swf on flash professional. I might try splitting the URLREQUEST into different class file. Not sure if it would make it better or worse tho.

Comment: And i tried packaging it into APK, installed it on my phone, and it ran correctly twice, i think out of maybe 50 times.... But it doesn't run on the debug in flash pro. But ran ok, when it is on localhost, and i just uploaded the php onto the remote server again. Double checked the URL.....still the same thing, i will try splitting the loader into different class in a little

Comment: Yup, just tried it, the problem was too many URLREQUEST in a class file, i split that into a separate class, and then addChild, it works and speed up a lot as well